# delete cart item from the carts when user login from other system

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to delete all cart items from the cart when customer login from the different system using woo-commerce. I am newbie to wordpress, so Can any one help me for this?

Comment: "login from the different system". What did you mean? Connecting from deferent `IP`, `Browser`?

Comment: Connecting from deferent `IP`

Comment: You can try hooking to the `init` action with the `global $woocommerce;   
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();` Also you will need a way to track the `IP` with the correct WOO session.

Comment: can you please explain in detail i am totally new to wordpress. so i dont know where to write your code

Comment: I you are new, the first thing is to learn how to create a plugin, look here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin